# What feat heals a spell's caster when that spell deals damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, content-identification

I could've sworn that there's a feat that allows a spell's caster to heal hp damage whenever the caster deals damage with a spell. For example, a caster casts *magic missile* at a foe and the caster regains some hp if the foe is dealt damage by the spell.

Is there a feat that has an effect like this? Alternatively, if there isn't a feat that does this, is there something else that *does* do this like a magic item or a special ability granted by a base class, prestige class, or template?

Comment: Are you asking for help finding that one feat, or are you asking for any/all ways to add healing ability? The post is currently asking both, making it unclear what the question actually is, and more likely to attract answers that  guess wrong and don't solve your actual problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Any that meet that criteria would help, but mainly the one. And in some form that won't require multiclassing.

Comment: This site generally produces better answers when the question is focused on one question at a time, which is why we have a one-post, one-question policy. Can you pick one or the other? You can always ask the other one separately after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Draconic Heritage (Races of the Dragon p.102), Draconic Vigor(Dragon Magic p.17)

Draconic Vigor heals you for 1hp per spell level of the spell cast.

Comment: +1 either way, but in my opinion, this answer would be improved by noting how *ridiculously bad* this feat is. Warning readers about traps is an important part of how we can help players of systems like 3.5 that have a lot of them.